# jQuery Validate with Charge plugin

Tags: plugin-charge, jquery

I'm trying to validate my form before the charge.js is triggered.

I've decided to drop submit button in favour of a standard button and then use valid() method to process submit, so this is what I have now:

```
<form id="charge-form">
<!-- some fields here !-->
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Subscribe">
</form>

<script>
  $("#charge-form").validate();
  $("#charge-form").charge();
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($("#charge-form").valid()) {
        $("#charge-form").submit();
    }
  })
</script>
```

Validation works, and when testing the conditional statement with console.log it also works properly, but when actually used it gives $form.get(...).submit is not a function in the console in charge.js

[image]

Did anyone make jQuery Validate work with Charge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, this has nothing to do with charge.js, one simply can't have a button with an id="submit" as weird things will happen - [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript)

```
<input type="button" id="otherThanSubmit">
```

this works fine